# Facing error in AppDelegate.h file – Expo/Expo.h’ file not found

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, react-native-unimodules

I am trying to migrate form `react-native-unimodules` to expo modules. I followed this documentation and everything is fine in `Android`, But in `iOS` getting mentioned error in `AppDelegate.h`.

This is how my AppDelegate.h looks like this,

[image]

In documentation it’s been mentioned just to add import <Expo/Expo.h>. But there isn’t much description about this line.

Will this file be created automatically?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.expo.dev/bare/installing-expo-modules/#manual-installation

`yarn add expo` is featured in the above.